# How to get the mean of nsmallest from Pandas DataFrame using Datetimes

Tags: python, performance, pandas, datetime

I am trying to get the nsmallest and the mean of nsmallest from a dataframe by selecting dates.

From this DataFrame:

```
                    2       chk2       chk3     val
0                                                  
2016-08-01  31.340000 2016-05-09 2016-08-08  18.605
2016-08-02  32.359999 2016-05-09 2016-08-08  18.605
2016-08-03  32.089001 2016-05-09 2016-08-08  18.605
2016-08-04  31.194001 2016-05-09 2016-08-08  18.605
2016-08-05  30.585000 2016-05-09 2016-08-08  18.605
2016-08-08  20.490000 2016-05-09 2016-08-08  18.605
2016-08-09  20.135000 2016-08-08 2016-11-21  18.605
2016-08-10  19.103000 2016-08-08 2016-11-21  18.605
2016-08-11  19.452000 2016-08-08 2016-11-21  18.605
2016-08-12  19.241001 2016-08-08 2016-11-21  18.605
2016-08-15  19.645000 2016-08-08 2016-11-21  18.605
2016-08-16  20.124000 2016-08-08 2016-11-21  18.605
2016-08-17  19.863001 2016-08-08 2016-11-21  18.605
2016-08-18  19.667999 2016-08-08 2016-11-21  18.605
2016-08-19  19.083001 2016-08-08 2016-11-21  18.605
2016-08-22  18.163000 2016-08-08 2016-11-21  18.605
2016-08-23  18.948001 2016-08-08 2016-11-21  18.605
2016-08-24  19.329999 2016-08-08 2016-11-21  18.605
2016-08-25  19.735999 2016-08-08 2016-11-21  18.605
2016-08-26  19.769999 2016-08-08 2016-11-21  18.605
2016-08-29  18.704000 2016-08-08 2016-11-21  18.605
2016-08-30  19.756000 2016-08-08 2016-11-21  18.605
2016-08-31  19.931000 2016-08-08 2016-11-21  18.605
```

This gives me `nsmallest` of the entire Dataframe, seems to ingore the dates in `chk2` and `chk3`  have changed after the first week

```
df.query('chk2 <= index <= chk3')[2].nsmallest(3)

0
2016-08-22    18.163000
2016-08-29    18.704000
2016-08-23    18.948001
Name: 2, dtype: float64
```

Applying this function -- it seems to ingore the change in dates in the first week.

```
def _test(row):
#     df.query('chk2 <= index <= chk3')[2].nsmallest(3).mean()
    return df.query('chk2 <= index <= chk3')[2].nsmallest(3).mean()

    #return df.query('row[1] <= index <= row[2]')[2].nsmallest(3).mean() 
    #UndefinedVariableError: ("name 'row' is not defined", u'occurred at index 2016-08-01 00:00:00')


df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 23 entries, 2016-08-01 to 2016-08-31
Data columns (total 3 columns):
2       23 non-null float64
chk2    23 non-null datetime64[ns]
chk3    23 non-null datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float64(1)
memory usage: 736.0 bytes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you can use `groupby` to get the date changes and then `transform` to perform your operation on those groups.

```
(df.query('chk2 <= index <= chk3').groupby(['chk2', 'chk3'])
                                  .transform(lambda x: x.nsmallest(3).mean())
```

**Demo**

```
>>> df
                    2       chk2       chk3
2016-08-01  31.340000 2016-05-09 2016-08-08
2016-08-02  32.359999 2016-05-09 2016-08-08
...
2016-08-30  19.756000 2016-08-08 2016-11-21
2016-08-31  19.931000 2016-08-08 2016-11-21

>>> (df.query('chk2 <= index <= chk3').groupby(['chk2', 'chk3'])
                                      .transform(lambda x: x.nsmallest(3).mean())
                 2
2016-08-01  27.423
2016-08-02  27.423
2016-08-03  27.423
2016-08-04  27.423
2016-08-05  27.423
2016-08-08  27.423
2016-08-09  18.605
2016-08-10  18.605
2016-08-11  18.605
2016-08-12  18.605
2016-08-15  18.605
2016-08-16  18.605
2016-08-17  18.605
2016-08-18  18.605
2016-08-19  18.605
2016-08-22  18.605
2016-08-23  18.605
2016-08-24  18.605
2016-08-25  18.605
2016-08-26  18.605
2016-08-29  18.605
2016-08-30  18.605
2016-08-31  18.605
```